# Making a variable out of string key inside a dictionary

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have a class:

```
class Employee():
    raise_amount = 1.05
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
    
    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amount)
        print(self.pay)
```

I can instantiate an object like so:

```
emp_1 = Employee('John', 'Doe', 10000)
```

I have a dictionary:

```
b = {'first':['John', 'Doe', 10000], 'second' : ['Danis', 'Jones', 20000]}
```

I want to instantiate two objects, `first` and `second` from the `b` dictionary with values they hold.

I tried:

```
for k,v in b.items():
    k = Employee(v[0],v[1],v[2])
first.pay
```

> NameError: name 'first' is not defined

How can I achieve creating objects from a dictionary in which the key is the variable name of the class instance and the parameters are the values each key holds?

Comment: Anytime you think you need to create variables whose names are based off of the contents of strings, you're doing it wrong. It's the old "variable number of variables" thing - In the end, you'll want to store `Employee` objects in some kind of collection. It looks like you want a list of `Employee` objects. If you are really attached to accessing your employess via the strings `"first"` and `"second"`, then you would put them in a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. But I still want to know if its even possible to achieve such thing in python when a variable name is taken from a list or dictionary key, etc?

Comment: It is possible using `global()` or `locals()`, but not advisable as you'll run into scoping issues, and generally it's just not a good practice as it make your code less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one thing you are doing wrong apart from your requirement to create variables outta that dictionary `b`. Try this :

```
for k,v in b.items():
    b[k] = Employee(v[0],v[1],v[2])
print(b['first'].pay)
```

This would give output `10000`.
Doing `k = Employee(v[0],v[1],v[2])` inside the for loop doesn't modify the dictionary `b` itself.

If you don't want to modify the dictionary `b` but want to introduce the keys and their corresponding instance values as local variables, you can try the following (but this is not something suggested) :

```
b = {'first':['John', 'Doe', 10000], 'second' : ['Danis', 'Jones', 20000]}
c = {}
for k,v in b.items():
    c[k] = Employee(*v)
locals().update(c)
print(first.pay)
print(second.pay)
```

Output :

```
10000
20000
```

Comment: I do not want to modify the dictionary, it only acts as a source for the variable creation, if its, of course, possible.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you are using `c` set?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis First of all, `c` isn't a set, it's a dictionary. Again if yoy did `b[k] = Employee(*v)` inside for loop that'll modify the dict `b` but you need to keep `b` intact. That's why we're assigning a vacant dict outside, assigning the key-values in the for loop and then updating the local variables dict with our new dict `c`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind creating a new [collection](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html), perhaps following can be helpful:

```
all_employees = []
for _, v in b.items():
    all_employees.append(Employee(v[0], v[1], v[2]))

for e in all_employees:
    print("first: ", e.first)
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'Employee' object is not subscriptable`  - I get this error.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis, I missed .append(). Updated!